# Auto refresh Pivot Table in same sheet as Source Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

How can I have a defined table and a Pivot Table auto refreshing every time the defined table changes? I'm using this code and it loops infinitely:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets("Totales").PivotTables("Tabla dinámica1").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

It does not loop when the Pivot Table is in another worksheet.

Comment: there's a couple points of clarity here: *defined table changes* - **1)** does `defined table` mean ListObject (data table) or just cells with data in table like format? **2)** does change happen via manual entry and / or formula result and / or linked data refresh? *does not loop when the Pivot Table is in another worksheet.* - can you be more specific? why do you need loop, Or do you just need this to fire when the table changes? If so, in which module does this code reside?

Comment: I'd suggest that it's better to have the source data in another sheet, and run the refresh code using a Worksheet_Deactivate event. Otherwise the PivotTable will refresh after each and every change that a user makes to the source data, and if they are making multilpe changes then this will likely drive them crazy. Whereas if they are making changes to the source data in another sheet, then the PivotTable will only refresh when they are done...which is when they deselect the source data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure should be placed in Excel Object which represents sheet being source of your data for Pivot Table. For example assuming that your data for pivot table is in Sheet1 you should place your code in Sheet1 Microsoft Excel Object:

[image]

Assuming that your pivot table is in Sheet3 the code (placed in Sheet1 object) should look similiary to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("Tabla dinámica1").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```